# Columns aren't showing in a calculated table, in SSAS Tabular Editor v 2.16.1

Tags: database-design, calculated-columns, custom-fields, ssas-tabular

I created calculated table in SSAS Tabular Editor (version 2.16.1 if that's important)

But I can only see my calculated column which I created separately

No summarized columns from the code below are shown in my new table in SSAS Tabular Editor, why?

Is there a settings I have to change in order to see the columns?

After I deploy, I can see my new tbl and columns in Power BI (but not in SSAS Tabular)

here is my code in DAX, in SSAS Tabular Model:

```
      SUMMARIZE (
                 'zzParam_DiagnosisGrp',
                 'zzParam_DiagnosisGrp'[EHRProgramWHID],
                 'zzParam_DiagnosisGrp'[ClientWHID],
                 'zzParam_DiagnosisGrp'[Date],
                 'zzParam_DiagnosisGrp'[Diagnosis Category],
                 'zzParam_DiagnosisGrp'[Diagnosis Classification]
              )
```

Here is what I see in SSAS Tabular after the code, and after I created 1 more calculated column:

[image]

Here is what I see in Power BI:

(These fields I am expecting to see in SSAS Tabular)

[image]

Please HELP!

Answer (score 1):

The columns won't show up until you deploy.

Here is what I see after creating the table with Tabular Editor 2.16.4 and SSAS Tabular 2017:

[image: Calculated Table with blue question mark icon]

The blue question mark icon indicates that you need to deploy.

After I click the save icon to deploy, the icon changes and the columns show up:

[image: Calculated Table with formula icon and columns]